# How to give box shadow to a box that has lower z-index in css

Tags: shadow, css

Hi I am a little new to CSS-box shadow,

I have written the following code in HTML,

```
<div id="left_content"></div>
<div id="right_content"></div>
```

And Following code in CSS,

```
#left_content {
  width : 250px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color : #DDDDDD;
  position : fixed;
  z-index : 10;
  float: left;
}

#right_content{
  width : 700px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color : #FFFFFF;
  float : right;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -4px -2px 5px rgba(48, 50, 50, 0.9);
  -moz-box-shadow:    -4px -2px 5px rgba(48, 50, 50, 0.9);
  box-shadow:         -4px -2px 5px rgba(48, 50, 50, 0.9);
}
```

The left content is fixed, when we scroll the right content scrolls, the shadow is not getting applied.

I need the shadow to fall on the left content, I do not want increase the z-index of right content.

Any help would be appreciable.
thanks in advance.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not too sure about what you are saying and what exactly you want to do.
Could you be a little bit more precise?

Answer (score 0):

The z-index of the right DIV has to be higher than that of the left.

```
#right_content{
    z-index:11;
}
```

**Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ctnels/h5RzH/12/)**

Answer (score -1):

Try adding `margin-left` to your right-hand div:

```
#right_content {
  margin-left: 270px;
}
```

This accounts for the width of the left div, plus a `20px` margin.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h5RzH/).

Comment: Yeah got that, but if you observe(http://jsfiddle.net/h5RzH/) that the shadow that is appearing should come over the left content, not go under it..

Comment: the solution is correct, but its for the left section, but I need the shadow on the right edge of the left_content, but this shadow should be thrown by right content - thanks